# Which of the two is "mean independent" in econometrics?

Tags: econometrics

In my master econometrics class, the professor mentions "mean independence" and throughout his slides, he uses two definitions interchangeably:

1. $E[U|D=1]=E[U|D=0]$
2. $E[U|D]=0$

where $D$ is the binary variable, $D=1$ indicates the treated group, $D=0$ indicates the untreated group, and $U$ is the error term of a regression model.

For me these two imply different things:

The 1st means the expectation of error of the two subgroups are the same, which is a constant with respect to $D$.

The 2nd means $U$ is independent of $D$ and also conditional on $D$. The expectation of $U$ is 0, so the 2nd is actually "mean independence" + "zero expectation" to me.

Am I understanding correctly? If not, are they 2 different things or the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem confusing if one is not well-versed in the econometric lingo. :)

First thing one need to know is that in the purest form, that is, for two arbitrary random variables $X$ and $Y$, mean independence of $Y$ given $X$ means $E(Y|X)=E(Y)$.

Second, since we are talking about an error term $U$ here (instead of some generic r.v. $Y$), we have an additional property that $E(U)=0$.

This is why "mean independence of error term $U$ given $X$" can be expressed as $E(U|X)=0$.

A third thing here is that we have a special $X$ variable, which is a binary treatment variable $D$.

When $D$ takes only two values $\{0, 1\}$, it is equivalent to write $E(U|D)=0$ as $$E(U|D=1)=E(U|D=0)=0.$$

Furthermore, since $U$ is an error term, we must have $$0=E(U)=E(U|D=1)P(D=1)+E(U|D=0)P(D=0).$$

Under the condition $E(U|D=1)=E(U|D=0)$, the equation above gives
$E(U|D=1)=E(U|D=0)=0$.

Thus, the two conditions are equivalent: $$E(U|D=1)=E(U|D=0) \Leftrightarrow E(U|D=1)=E(U|D=0)=0.$$

To summarize, all the above arguments show that the two definitions in your question are equivalent and one can use them interchangeably.

P.S. Let me know if you spot any typo here.

Comment: Hi! Thank you it is very clear! Maybe in the formula following "Furthermore, since U is an error term, we must have..." the last probability should be P(D=0) instead of P(D=1)?

Comment: @ChengmouLei Thanks. I've fixed the typo.